# Are twisted versions of supersymmetric field theories supersymmetric on any general four manifold?

Tags: supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

Witten in his famous paper (Topological Quantum Field Theory) writes -- " I do not know whether twisted versions of other $\mathcal{N} \ge 2$ supersymmetric field theories will similarly be supersymmetric on a general four manifold."

Paper can be found here : https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104161738

Do we know this now after about 30 years ?